# jQuery: How to copy one value to another

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying (with C# and jQuery) to copy the value of one textbox to display in another textbox. Seems simple enough but something's wrong with my syntax. Do I need to use the equal operator instead?

```
return _browser.Execute("$('#" + toWhere + "').val('" + fromWhere + ".val()');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `_browser.Execute` works fine, I'd say the problem is that the contents of `val` don't have a jQuery call in there.

```
return _browser.Execute("$('#" + toWhere + "').val($('#" + fromWhere + ").val()');");
```

Comment: Yes, the _brower.Execute is part of a wrapper and works just fine. I agree that the jQuery call needed to be added however it is still not placing the value in the other textbox.